# Change default encoding of Hive data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have unicode data in a hive table which I am trying to view using pyspark.

```
sqlContext.table('mytable').select("column_containing_unicode_data").show(1)
```

Returns error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 75-76: ordinal not in range(256)

Any suggestions how I can read such data? I'm guessing I need to change the default encoding. I tried issuing:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import  udf
f=udf(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'),StringType())
sqlContext.table('mytable').select(f("column_containing_unicode_data").show()
```